# Does a "dumb" question solicit a downvote?

Tags: discussion

Let me qualify by explaining in this context, "dumb" means a perhaps silly mistake in code that is leading to an error. If the question is well asked, does this deserve a downvote? There definitely seems to be a culture of doing this, which I feel is perhaps wrong?

Comment: I think the general consensus is that people are free to vote as they please as long as it is based on the *content* (rather than, say, in retaliation for a suspected downvote on them).

Comment: Even the most trivial questions can sometimes be useful. Once in a while I even upvote questions that I closevote for; precisely because the author made sufficient effort at writing a coherent title and code excerpts, presented prior attempts, or made it somehow otherwise Google-find-worthy. (It's rare though. Most syntax/typo questions deserve no more attention than the closevote.)

Comment: More importantly, does a dumb question get you a dunce hat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Votes primarily indicate usefulness, aside from the obvious "everyone does as he pleases" aspect.

If someone posts a syntax error then that is almost always never useful to someone else. There can be a zillion different causes for the same syntax error and in the end it can be trivially fixed by simply looking at code samples in tutorials or documentation and by learning the basics of the language.

If you have a syntax error then you didn't put in the effort I expect to find it, simple as that.

A logical error on the other hand can be a perfectly valid question but what I want to see in those is that the user made a good attempt at finding out the problem and to see that there is enough knowledge on the side of the asker that tells me they will be able to understand the answer (or work with it).

If the problem can be trivially found by debugging then this will also incur my downvote-rage.

Of course all of this is moot since there is only one rule: *everyone votes how they want to*.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it kinda depends.  Anyone can make a 'silly mistake' and still be stumped for days with it, (I've certainly done that).

If the error could have been spotted immediately from compiler/linker error messages, or by a trivial amount of debugging, then I often gift a downvote, otherwise no.

Comment: I agree, my issue is with people downvoting the first case because I guess they feel it is so obvious to them it should be obvious to the novice.

Comment: An other good reason for downvoting: When just searching for the title gets you a good answer...